# Generate SPSS File using PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, csv, plsql, spss

## Problem:

I am looking for a way to generate a SPSS file using PL/ SQL. Currently, I am able to generate a .csv file with roughly 300-400 columns. I have tried to google and didn't have any luck in finding a way to generate SPSS file using PL/SQL.

## Expected Solution:

Either generate a SPSS file directly OR use some kind of java class like one this program SPSS Writer uses  to convert the .csv file into SPSS. My understanding is that we would need to provide the metadata file in order to convert the csv file into SPSS.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could read the .csv file into SPSS then have SPSS generate its own data file. [Here is a document which describes how to read .csv files into SPSS](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/modules/input.htm). Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob! I am more interested in being able to generate a .sav file to provide it to my clients. They are currently using the .csv file that we provide to import it into SPSS. But, they feel that SPSS format file would be better for them to handle their requirements. Is it possible to generate a .sav file using PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: Not so far as I know. Perhaps you could submit this as an enhancement request to Allroundautomations. However, using PL/SQL Developer you can export data to Excel, and then save the spreadsheet as a .xlsx file. Then, [look at this page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Excel_file_set_up.htm) to see how to import an Excel spreadsheet into SPSS. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to generate a sav file without SPSS you can write a program using the SPSS io modules available free via the SPSS community website.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer the question. Is there a way you can generate a .sav file directly using IDE like PL SQL Developer? Currently we are generating a .csv file, but it appears that a .sav file would be a better format for my clients. I am interested to see if we could integrate that SPSS IO module with the Java Poller that we are currently using to drop the file to a folder.